# Does greedy circle packing exhaust the measure of every bounded open set in the plane?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, plane-geometry, circle-packing

The *greedy* circle packing of a bounded region in the plane is the result of placing at each stage the largest possible disk into the region that remains uncovered.

The greedy circle packing of a square, for example, begins by placing the inscribed circle, and then four more circles, one in each corner, and then eight more circles adjacent to them in the corners, and so forth. It is not difficult to prove that the total measure of these circles in the limit is equal to the measure of the original square.

One way to see this is to observe that at each stage, we are packing circles into the triangular-like region between three other circles (or the straight lines of the square boundary).

[image: greedy circle packing of region between three circles][image: another greedy circle packing]

The key observation is that we can always cover at least a fixed nonzero proportion $r$ of such a triangular-like region by placing finitely many circles, at least 1%, say. This is enough to imply that in the limit we achieve full measure, since if it were less, then at some finite stage we would be close enough to that value so that proportion $r$ of what remains would bring us over the supposed limit. So the packing limit must be full measure.

This argument works more generally with many other figures. My question is whether it works with every open set.

**Question.** Must the greedy circle packing of a bounded open set $U$ exhaust the measure of $U$?

The greedy aspect is required, since it is easy to find non-greedy but maximal circle packings of arbitrarily small measure—simply start by placing a circle of area at most $\varepsilon/2$, then another of size at most $\varepsilon/4$, and so forth, in such a way that the resulting disks are dense in the region. You can't add any more circles, so the packing is maximal, but the total measure is at most $\varepsilon$.

Perhaps one can make a counterexample to the question by starting with a square, and then strategically omitting points here and there so as to form obstacles to the circles that might be placed. For example, if you remove the center point of the square, then the largest circle that fits is much smaller than the full inscribed circle. By subsequently removing more points, one can make the next greedy circle much smaller still.

But I haven't been able to make this idea work while controlling the measure of the closure of the omitted points. For example, if the closure of the omitted points included the boundaries of all the placed circles, we would be in the fat Cantor set type situation, and the circles might still exhaust the measure of the region. Perhaps this always happens, and this way of thinking might turn into a proof of the positive result. I am unsure.

In one dimension, the answer is affirmative, since the bounded open set simply *is* the greedy circle packing of it. Perhaps the question is interesting in higher dimensions. (Thanks to Twitter user [lemma Meringue](https://twitter.com/lemma_meringue/status/1769006401060229375).)

(Note: Please help me retag, since this question isn't in my usual area and I am unsure which tags are best. Also, apologies if the question turns out to be much easier than I have realized.)

Comment: Greedy packing with squares instead of circles is exhaustive, because the squares can abut one another with no gaps, and thereby fill out any open region.

Comment: I don't understand the remark about the squares: they would fit snugly only if you were allowed to arrange them. (Or did you mean squares with sides parallel to the coordinate axes?)

Comment: See "Apollonian gasket" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollonian_gasket ... The reminder (what is not covered by the disks) has Hausdorff dimension about 1.3 (which is stronger than merely saying 2-dimensional Lebesgue measure zero).

Comment: @GeraldEdgar I have known about Apollonian gaskets, but is the general case here of exhausting an arbitrary open set still an instance of this phenomenon? After all, you might often be placing a circle that abuts the boundary of the region rather than only other circles. Does the fractal dimension claim still hold?

Comment: @ChristianRemling Yes, I think you are right about the squares, since it can happen that the largest possible square does not align with the previous squares. It seems that Fedor's argument, however, also works with squares.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar For example, it seems to me that one can make a maximal non-greedy circle packing, where at every stage the next circle, of radius $\sqrt{\varepsilon}/n$, is tangent to two previous circles, but still the circles are dense, since the sum-of-radii diverges. In this case, the fractal dimension will be 2, since the remainder will have positive measure.

Comment: This (not mine, really) argument works in every metric measure space in which the so-called doubling condition works: the ratio of measures of two concentric balls with one radius twice more than another should be uniformly bounded.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes, the reason is the same as in the proof of Vitali covering theorem. It suffices that $U$ has finite measure, allowed to be unbounded.

If $D_i$ are the greedy-chosen (closed, but this is not crucial of course) disks with centers $p_i$ and radii $r_i$, let $U_i$ be the disks with centers $p_i$ and radii $2r_i$.

Note that the sum of measures of $D_i$'s is finite, since they are disjoint and $U$ has finite measure. It yields that $\lim r_i=0$ and also that the the sum of measures of $U_i$ is finite.

**Lemma.** Every point $x$ which is not covered by $D_i$'s lies in the union of $U_k$ for $k>N$ (for every $N$).

**Proof.** Since $x\notin \cup_{j\leqslant N} D_j$ and this set is closed, there exists a disk $V\subset U$ with some radius $r>0$ centered in $x$ and not intersecting with $\cup_{j\leqslant N} D_j$. Since $\lim r_i=0$, there exists minimal $m$ for which $r_m<r$. By greedy procedure, since we did not choose $V$ or larger disk on the $m$-th step, $V$ has non-empty intersection with some $D_j$, $j<m$. Thus by the choice of $V$ we get $j>N$, and by minimality of $m$ we get $r_j\geqslant r$. Therefore $x\in U_j$.

It remains to note that since the sum of measures of $U_i$ is finite, the tail sum over $i>N$ may be made arbitrarily small if $N$ is large.